# linux created my executable file with a different name

Tags: cmd.exe

I utilized the command g++ -o assign3 assign3b.cpp to create my executable file in linux, however, the executable file that linux created was assign3. This command is supposed to create an assign3b executable file. I utilized this exact command to create my assign3a executable file with no issue. Thoughts?

Comment: According to the command you provided, the output file, was properly named assign3.  `-o assign3` does not contained the word `assign3b` like you think it does.

Comment: Thank you. You were correct. I didn't realize I was misinterpreting the meaning of the command. I didn't see your comment until now. Much appreciated! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!!
g++ is the command to invoke the compiler.
-o is the operator for g++ and signifies that I the programmer will specify the output file

*here's my correction: my output file should have been assign3b

the next command after that is my input file assign3b.cpp

In total it should look like this: g++ -o assign3b assign3b.cpp

This tells the compiler to create an executable file named assign3b with an input file of assign3b.cpp